# Whats wrong with iMacros EVAL statement?

Tags: eval, imacros

This is the code

```
VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE C:\Users\user\Documents\iMacros\Datasources
SET !DATASOURCE LINK.csv

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=*
TAB T=2
SET !VAR1 {{!COL1}}
SET !VAR2 {{!URLCURRENT}}
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var url_current=\"!VAR2\"; var url_last=\"!VAR1\"; if(   url_current==url_last ) {var action = \"Unlike\";} else {action = \"Like\";} action;"}
PROMPT {{!VAR3}}
```

every time i run it i get the following error code

```
wrong format of SET command, line 11 (Error code: 910)
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong with the code

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a braces problem. Try in this way:

```
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var url_current=\"{{!VAR2}}\"; var url_last=\"{{!VAR1}}\"; if(   url_current==url_last ) {var action = \"Unlike\";} else {action = \"Like\";} action;")
```

Comment: Copied, pasted & played the macro. No any problems. Nevertheless try a shortened form: `SET !VAR3 EVAL("('{{!VAR2}}' == '{{!VAR1}}') ? 'Unlike' : 'Like';")`

Comment: hmm worked on copy and pasting i don't know how thanks very much -- up-voted and accepted